# How do i insert data in MongoDB from node.js from form

Tags: mongodb, registration

Hi I am trying to make a registration form and i want to store data to MongoDB with node.js and from node.js I want to request an HTML form the email and password and then store that data to MongoDB.

Anyone know how?

Comment: use https://mongoosejs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get info from the form using mongoose(MongoDB) and node.js you do:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(mongoString, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String
});

const User = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);

app.post('/register', async (req, res, next) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email
  })

  if (user) {
    res.redirect('/register');
  } else {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        new User({
          email: req.body.email,
          password: hash
        }).save()
        req.flash('error', 'Account made, please log in.');
        res.redirect('/login');
      });
    });
  }
});
```